# why are my faces in the cloth simulation going haywire

Tags: sculpting, uv-image-editor, cloth-simulation

i was following the blender guru couch tutorial , but as soon as i started sculpting the cusion the cusion went haywire , can anybody tell me the solution[image]

Answer (score 0):

i solved it , i had not applied the modifyiers